# Как сделать, чтобы наименование списка подставлялось в цикл из textBox1.Text?

Tags: c#

```
    for (int i = 0; i < linklList.Count; i++)
{
    String c = linklList[i].Text;
    textBox1.AppendText("Позиция № " + (i + 1).ToString() +  "\r\n");
}
```

Как правильно прописать, чтобы в

- `linklList.Count`
- `linklList[i].Text`

вместо **linklList** подставилось значение из **textBox1.Text**?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, LinklList> lookup = new Dictionary<string, LinklList>();
lookup["a"] = new LinklList();
lookup["b"] = new LinklList();
...

if (lookup.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text))
{
  LinklList list = lookup[textBox1.Text];
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    String c = list[i].Text;
    textBox1.AppendText("Позиция № " + (i + 1).ToString() +  "\r\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку "The type or namespace name 'LinklList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". См .скрин http://prntscr.com/dl6dpt. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Ошибку  вроде убрал, но что-то не работает.  Код выглядит так см. ссылку https://codeshare.io/5wgXR5